# .htaccess - Redirect to parent directory if file does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have amp version for some pages on my website, but for some - only regular version. In general the structure is like this:

```
\
\page1.htm
\page2.htm
...
\amp\
\amp\page1.htm
```

So page1.htm has its amp version, but `page2.htm` - doesnt have.
When user retrive `\amp\page2.htm` instead of 404 I would like to serve `page2.htm` from root directory.

I've tried to make redirect via .htaccess, but it doesnt work correctly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/amp/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/amp/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What is wrong with this code? Why I still getting 404?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one that underlines the subtleties of mod_rewrite. The short answer is, there are two ways to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/amp/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . https://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Several important differences:

1. I'm capturing the trailing part of the REQUEST_URI in the RewriteCond rather than in the RewriteRule and then referencing it using PERCENT 1 (`%1`) rather than DOLLAR 1 (`$1`)
2. I'm using REQUEST_FILENAME to see if a file exists on the filesystem rather than DOCUMENT_ROOT/REQUEST_URI because the REQUEST_URI can be anything and may or may not coincide with what is on the filesystem (as your example demonstrates).
3. The `RewriteRule` matches on everything (the `.` rather than `/amp/`)

Or you can do:

```
RewriteBase /amp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^amp(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Why these two different approaches work revolves around this quote from the official mod_rewrite documentation (emphasis mine):

> Note that mod_rewrite tries to guess whether you have specified a **file-system** path or a **URL-path** by checking to see if the first segment of the path exists at the root of the file-system. For example, if you specify a Substitution string of /www/file.html, then this will be treated as a URL-path unless a directory named www exists at the root or your file-system (or, in the case of using rewrites in a .htaccess file, relative to your document root), in which case it will be treated as a file-system path.

The first approach treats things as a URL-path while the second approach treats things as a file-path.

I'm going to guess that the first approach is more in line with what you'll be needing as amp solutions are often "generated" (and don't live as flat files on the filesystem) and thus, you are more interested in working with the input as a URL-path than a file-path.

And before you think, "Wow! How can people keep this stuff in their brains?". I only have a vague understanding of the mod_rewrite rules and actually had to re-read the documentation and run a number of tests to clarify things for myself before writing this up.

Hope this helps.

Some URLs for reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule
- https://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/